# Search the best match comparing prefixes

Tags: python-3.x, string-matching, prefix

I have the `numbers codes` and `text codes` like in `table1` below. And I have the `numbers to search` like in `table2`
for which I want to get the best match for a `prefix of minimun length of 3` comparing from left to rigth and show as answer the corresponding `TEXT CODE`.

- If there is an exact match, that would be the answer.
- If there is no any value that has at least 3 length prefix then answer would be "not found".

I show some comments explaining the conditions applied in answer expected for each `Number to search` next to table2.
[image]

My current attempt shows the exact matches, but I'm not sure how to compare the values to search for the other conditions, when there is no exact match.

```
ncode = ["88271","1893","107728","4482","3527","71290","404","5081","7129","33751","3","40489","107724"]
tcode = ["RI","NE","JH","XT","LF","NE","RI","XT","QS","XT","YU","WE","RP"]
tosearch = ["50923","712902","404","10772"]

out = []
out.append([])
out.append([])

for code in tosearch:
    for nc in ncode:
        if code == nc:
            indexOfMatched = ncode.index(nc)
            out[0].append(nc)
            out[1].append(tcode[indexOfMatched])

>>> out
[['404'], ['RI']]
```

The expected output would be

```
out = [
        ['50923',     '712902', '404', '10772'], 
        ['NOT FOUND', 'NE',     'RI',  'JH'   ]
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution you might consider would be the fuzzy-match library. It compares strings and calculates a similarity score. It really shines with strings rather than numbers, but it could easily be applied to find similar results in your prefix numbers.

Check out [fuzzy-match here](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzy-match/).

Here is a well written [fuzzy-match tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python).

Comment: thanks for info shared. It seems to be a kind of what I'm trying to do. Using this I'd need to know what percentage of match would be good to select. More than 0.5, more than 0.65 etc.

Comment: @GerCas, I think it will just take a bit of trial and error to dial in what the error percentage you are happy with is. I'd expect an accuracy of about 80% would be good. That would allow a five-digit number to be off by a single digit and still appear in the results. It gets a bit harder with shorter numbers like '404', as that might not allow an error. There are a couple of different fuzzy match methods that can be used that might work better in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I tested that fuzzy match with several possibilities and doesn't give the expected answer for what I need in many cases when I use actual input data. Since my question is about matching based on prefix and this fuzzy method looks string in any position. Thanks anyway